# Single User single computer app : Local database vs. database on a sql express

Tags: .net, sql-server-express, local-database

I'm building an application for a client, single user single computer only.

If I use a local database, I want to know if a client would need to install SQL 2008 express edition to run the application? Where is the local DB located (for backup purposes) if this was published as a click once application?
(OR)
Would it be better if I moved the DB over to the SQL Express and wired the application to use the data from the DB on express.

All your help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will be using one user database locally I would suggest that you consider integrating it in your application and use databases like [SQL Server compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) or [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) (it has a .NET library that you can download and use and it's pretty fast and compact).

Comment: SQL lite is a great option, the only problem that I see with it is the ability to restore it in case of a crash. not sure how feasible that would be. What if I had some datafixes to do? I would have to push them from the application right? no way to see the data like we would if we attached a query analyzer to SQL express?

Answer (score 1):

there are a number of databases to choose from. for a single user local app I find even the express sql engines are overkill. either SqlCE, Sqlite or a nosql option like a persistent hashtable or ensent would be worth investigating.